# How to detect AppBarButtonStyle PointerPressed and PointerReleased events?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a button which is defined in XAML like this:

```
<Button x:Name="CommandsBtn"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Style="{StaticResource ControlsAppBarButtonStyle}"
        Click="Commands_Click"
        FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"
        Background="{x:Null}"
        BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
        Margin="0"
        Grid.Column="3" />
```

and the ControlsAppBarButtonStyle is defined like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ControlsAppBarButtonStyle"
       TargetType="ButtonBase"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
  <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId"
          Value="CommandsAppBarButton" />
  <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name"
          Value="Controls" />
  <Setter Property="Content"
          Value="" />
</Style>
```

I would like to detect the PointerPressed and PointerReleased events. I do detect the click event.

Tried to do:

```
CommandsBtn.PointerPressed += CommandsBtn_PointerPressed;
CommandsBtn.PointerReleased += CommandsBtn_PointerReleased;
```

But the events are not being fired (or at least are not getting to my page).

How do I do that?

Thanks,
EitanB

Comment: What you like to do with that. If you tried to do some state change in press, release events you can do that in corresponding Visual States.

Comment: When the user presses the button I turn on a motor, as he releases the button the motor stops. I would like to use the AppBarButtonStyle button. Thx Eitan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind to the Button's IsPressed property and handle changes of your bound property to see the changes. Consider using RepeatButton too.

Comment: Does "IsPressed" fire an event? If not, it will not be a solution to my needs.

Comment: It doesn't by itself but if you bind another property to it you can fire whatever you want.

Comment: hi, 
What do you mean by "bind another property"?
Thx Eitan

Comment: Well, instead of handling events you can create a property in your view model that you bind to the IsPressed property and in which you can handle these changes appropriately. You would set on the button `IsPressed="{Binding YourProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"` and make sure the object that defines YourProperty is the `DataContext`. Other than that I created an attached behavior `ButtonBaseExtensions.ButtonStateEventBehavior` you can see here http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1e9b95dbae1c#WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/Views/Controls.Extensions/ButtonBaseExtensionsTestPage.xaml

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will study the WinRT XAML Toolkit, and thanks for being involved in this project.

Comment: Make sure you download the latest source from the Source tab: http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1e9b95dbae1c